# Can I put wheels on a bunk bed?

Tags: safety, furniture, design

I can't find any information about safety related to having caster wheels (the kind that can swivel) on a bunk bed.

The only concern I have is if the child leans against the wall while on top and the bed pushed out. Allowing the child to fall between the bed and wall.

This risk could be reduced with casters that can lock.

I want to have wheels to make it easier for my wife to make the bed.

Comment: You should probably have a way to retract the wheels so that by default the bed rests on its own legs. Only when you go to move it does it rest on the wheels.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I can't picture how that could be done on something large like a bed. I have wheel platforms in the shop that do this but they use a foot peddle to lift one end.

Comment: A lever some ball bearings on dowels and a track for them, http://woodgears.ca/mobile_base/table_saw.html

Comment: You're not concerned about the kids giving each other bunk-bed rides?

Comment: Can you clarify this question to make it a little more apparent how it is related to woodworking?

Comment: I'm afraid I have to close this question as off-topic as it doesn't relate to woodworking.

Comment: @drs I think this would be an OK fit for DIY though

Comment: @Matt, Unfortunately, I don't think so.  They're standard usually is "Does your question relate to something that comes with your house when you buy it".  Beds don't fit there either :/.

Comment: @drs My bad. If that is the loose criteria some other stuff has certainly slipped in there.

Comment: @Matt that's okay man. I totally see how this isn't woodworking. It could be migrated over to the parenting section, but I think the accepted answer nailed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My dad put plastic caster wheels on the twin beds he made for my brother and I as kids (granted, these were not bunk beds).  On carpet, the wheels made enough of a dimple that it took a bit of pushing to get them to move out of the dimple.  On wood floor, it will be much easier to push.

> The only concern I have is if the child leans against the wall while on top and the bed pushed out. Allowing the child to fall between the bed and wall.

This is a valid concern.  You could mitigate it by adding a railing on the wall-side of the bed, or possibly tying the bed to the wall when your wife doesn't need to change the sheets.  If you live in a seismic area (looking at you California), tying a bunk bed to the wall might be a good idea anyway.

From a purely mechanics point of view, adding casters won't make the bed more tippy than if it had plain legs.  It would just feel more unstable since it can move side to side.

> This risk could be reduced with casters that can lock.

Depending on the floor you have, this might not make a big difference.  Plastic sliding on wood has a pretty low coefficient of friction.  It will be harder than if the wheels weren't locked, but not much.

You could also use some sort of chock block to keep the wheels from moving, similar to what you should do to a car when jacking it up for maintenance.

Comment: @JasonC, exactly what I was going for.

Comment: Oh yeah, I misread, guess I added nothing, ha. In that case: I second the idea of attaching the bed to the wall.